# Get UUID of BLE IOS Peripheral, not service UUID

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uuid, cbperipheralmanager

how is it possible to fetch the UUID from Peripheral side. Not the service UUIDs out of the advertising package.

Lets see it from the central side:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

What I need is the UUID out of `peripheral.identifier`, not the ones included in the `advertisementData`. I can fetch them from the central side, but I need to do this also from the peripheral side.

Comment: I am able to get service UUID from `[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]` , But how to get UUID of BLE (like `iBeacon`) device ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way do get UUID from `CBPeripheralManager` side.

Since this UUID is hard coded in Bluetooth chip,and people barely change their iPhone's Bluetooth chip，this method would be used to track down user ,which is versus to Apple's intend.

Apple banned UDID in iOS 5,banned MAC address in iOS 6.

So there is no reason Apple gave you access to Bluetooth UUID when Apple add `CBPeripheralManager`in iOS 6.